# Images look well in web version but in React Native Images are not getting rendered

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, react-native, image

Images are not getting rendered in frontend for some reason  , I can not figure out what is wrong . They look perfect when we run the same app on web , image is passed as a prop here in jpeg format

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

<Image source={image}/>
```

Comment: You have to provide the `width` and `height` props to `<Image />` component.

Comment: I had that already but i found the issue , i was not using <Image source={{uri:image}}/>